# Webpage elements that are dynamic in nature?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How can I interact with elements on a website that uses dynamically generated classes or IDs, which change on runtime and update when the page refreshes, using Selenium in Python?

I am totally unaware of the scenario, because i had not worked on these sites.
for reference, site is like "linkedin"

Comment: Do the elements have an `id` or a `class`? You can do lookups as normal.

Comment: If an element takes a while to appear, try to avoid sleeping for a fixed period. Instead do a "wait until element appears" - this will sample the DOM until your element is available or you hit a timeout limit.

Comment: ok got the solution thank u soo much for your suggestions. 
Now i am getting all the elements and than finding all the classes or IDs on run time and assigning those values to extract data from them...

Comment: You will have to decide what property to match on. For example, maybe there is a div with an `id` and then there are three buttons in there, and you know you want the last one. You can use `#container input:last-child` for that. Ultimately your question is "how do I write CSS (or XPath) selectors", and the main answer for that is "learn CSS or XPath selectors". The question is far too general, so you are (obviously) going to get vague answers.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a sample of the HTML that you are actually using, plus your best prior attempt at solving it yourself (with CSS or XPath) and then readers will be _much_ more able to help you.

Comment: It has been suggested that you could use Beautiful Soup. You mention that it has "limits" but do not explain what those limits are. Perhaps you need to go into detail about what "human-like" interaction you want to achieve programmatically.

Comment: "div with an id and then there are three buttons in there, and you know you want the last one. You can use #container input:last-child for that." thank you for this. I am already using this..
i know i didn't provide code for clarification but the thing is that this is my first question on stackoverflow so please ignore my unprofessional way to ask..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access elements on a website on which the elements are dynamically changing and if you are trying to get a link you can try using link_by_text or partial_link_text or if you are trying to get the element that is not link you can use CSS_Selector or XPATHS or FULL XPATH.

Comment: I am already using these methods to interact but the issue is, when we reload the page than it's xpath, CSS Selector is updated. So how to handle this scenario..?

Comment: Try getting all the tag and get data from it or try using Beautiful Soup

Comment: Beautiful Soup is not working because it has limits and i want a human like interaction with soup, or if you can give me example code of linkedin than may i get some help...
thank you soo much..

Answer (score -1):

Python program is dynamic in nature  because the type data type is checked during the runtime of the execution

Comment: "Dynamic" here refers to the browser DOM, not the programming language involved.

Comment: I know that, but the issue is that site is loading dynamically and generating all the classes randomly, so whenever page refreshes it changes the class or ID.